# SQL aggregate values and add new columns

Tags: sql, aggregate

I am having some trouble to aggregate data on row-inputs. I have two columns originally, but i want to split the data based on PortID and add five columns which now lie in the AssetClass column as row values.

[The first table is how the data is structured now, the second is what i want it to look like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ge5xa.png)

Anyone have any tips how to do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to pivot your data set. Below query will pivot you data set purely using UNION and GROUP BY Clause which will be supported by any database system. You can add your pivot asset class S,U,P inside set_union block as done for C,F

Alternatively, you can simply use [PIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver16) operator.

```
CREATE TABLE sample
(   
    id              int,
    port_id         nvarchar(10),
    percent_weight  int,
    asset_class     nvarchar(1)
);

INSERT INTO sample values
('1','SOL','15','C'),
('2','EID','20','C'),
('3','PAR','25','C'),
('45','SOL','30','F'),
('46','EID','40','F'),
('47','PAR','45','F')
;

SELECT
    port_id,
    MAX(C)  AS  C,
    MAX(F)  AS  F
FROM
(
SELECT
    id,
    port_id,
    percent_weight AS C,
    NULL AS             F
FROM
    sample
WHERE
    asset_class='C'
UNION
SELECT
    id,
    port_id,
    NULL            AS  C,
    percent_weight  AS  F
FROM
    sample
WHERE
  asset_class='F'
)set_union
GROUP BY 
    port_id
ORDER BY 
    id ASC;
```

Output:
[image]